# Stateful LSTM internal memory size

Tags: lstm, keras

I read [Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/) and I'm trying to understand the internal state of LSTM (`C_t`). According to [Stateful LSTM in Keras](http://philipperemy.github.io/keras-stateful-lstm/) (paragraph *Mastering stateful models*), sequence elements can be fed to a stateful LSTM network one by one (without sliding window).

Let's say I expect my sequences to have length of 50 or less. How do I define my LSTM to have enough internal memory to remember sequences of that length?

As I understand it:

- [Internal memory / internal state / `C_t`] is a vector whose length is the same as the depth of the recurrence in the network (the number of green boxes in the image below).
- It has nothing to do with the `units` parameter of the network (which is the number of output features)

[image] (picture from [here](http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/))

I ran a simple experiment to observe `C_t`:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers import LSTM
import numpy as np


batch_size = 1
timesteps = 1
input_features_count = 1
output_features_count = 1
inputs1 = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, input_features_count))
lstm1 = LSTM(units = output_features_count, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, stateful=True)(inputs1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=lstm1)
data = array([0.1]).reshape((batch_size, timesteps, input_features_count))
pred_seq, state_h, state_c = model.predict(data)
print(pred_seq.shape) # (1, 1, 1)
print(state_h.shape) # (1, 1)
print(state_c.shape) # (1, 1)


batch_size = 1
timesteps = 2
input_features_count = 3
output_features_count = 5
inputs1 = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, input_features_count))
lstm1 = LSTM(units = output_features_count, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, stateful=True)(inputs1)
model = Model(inputs=inputs1, outputs=lstm1)
data = array([1,2,3,4,5,6]).reshape((batch_size, timesteps, input_features_count))
pred_seq, state_h, state_c = model.predict(data)
print(pred_seq.shape) # (1, 2, 5)
print(state_h.shape) # (1, 5)
print(state_c.shape) # (1, 5)
```

And now I'm lost, because `C_t`'s length is always 1 (event with sliding window: 
 timesteps=2), which as I see it, is not enough memory to learn any sequence. I also cannot find a way to arbitrarily define internal memory size.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand it: [Internal memory / internal state / `C_t`] is a vector whose length is the same as the depth of the recurrence in the network (the number of green boxes in the image below).

Your understanding is flawed. The RNN cell's internal memory is **not** the same length as the number of time steps. Instead, at each time step, the memory of the cell is **updated.** The values of the cell change to reflect the model's understanding of what is "important to remember" given the model weights, its memory state from the previous time-step, and the input.

> How do I define my LSTM to have enough internal memory to remember sequences of that length?

This isn't how LSTMs work. Consider a very simple sequence, one that starts at 0 and adds 1 at each time step. Now I tell you that the value at $f(10)=10$. Do you need to know $f(9)=9, f(8)=8, \cdots, f(0)=0$ to predict $f(11)$? Of course not. LSTMs generalize this idea to more complex sequences by learning to approximate how the values change between time steps, and then applying that rule to make predictions.

> Is internal state a vector at all?

```
print(state_h.shape) # (1, 5)
print(state_c.shape) # (1, 5)
```

It looks like each is a vector!

> What determines it's length?

```
output_features_count = 5
lstm1 = LSTM(units = output_features_count, ...)
```

> Let's consider an example with a little more complex sub-sequences: [1,0,0,0]->1, [1,0,0,1]->2, [0,0,0,1]->3. Now in order to make a prediction (after the 4th input) we kind of have to remember the first and the second inputs (third is meaningless). I thought this information was stored in the internal state. Is that correct?

It uses the memory cells to *represent* the information from the first 3 states. It doesn't need to *explicitly store* that information in the "raw" form of the original sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would you mind clearing some things up? Is internal state a vector at all (according to the first link in my question it should be)? What determines it's length? Let's consider an example with a little more complex sub-sequences: [1,0,0,0]->1, [1,0,0,1]->2, [0,0,0,1]->3. Now in order to make a prediction (after the 4th input) we kind of have to remember the first and the second inputs (third is meaningless). I thought this information was stored in the internal state. Is that correct?

Comment: @gisek I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. Keras documentation is a little misleading: "units: Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space." I understood is as the number of features to predict, while it seems to be the length of internal state (some abstract representation of changes in a sequence). Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: I've only ever found the `Stan` documentation to be any good. A typical LSTM structure is [input] -> [LSTM units] -> [fully-connected layer(s)] -> [output]. So even if you just have 1 output, it could be helpful to have a number of LSTM units used simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, I've seen such models a lot in various examples. I'm wondering though, why not replace the fully-connected (Dense) layer with LSTM(units=1, return_sequences=false)? Does it make any difference?

Comment: I'm sure it makes a big difference! But note that you'd still need a way to "project down" to just 1 hidden unit, and the usual (only?) way to project from many-to-1 is by a fully-connected layer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79309/discussion-between-gisek-and-sycorax).